# Недопонимание с функцией select()

Tags: c++, linux, c

Функция `select()` выглядит следующим образом

```
int select(int nfds, fd_set *readfds, fd_set *writefds,
                  fd_set *exceptfds, struct timeval *timeout);
```

и у меня по ней возникает несколько вопросов:

1) Мне как-то смутно представляется, как она работает. Поправьте меня, если я неправ. Допустим, перед вызовом данной функции мы "вызвали" макрос

```
void FD_ZERO(fd_set *set);
```

чтобы не было мусора и макрос

```
void FD_SET(int fd, fd_set *set);
```

чтобы указать дескрипторы, которые нас интерессуют. После чего вызываем саму функцию и она блокируется до тех пор, пока один из наших дескрипторов не будет готов к чтению или записи (в зависимости от того, что мы указали при помощи макросов) или пока таймер не истечет, или пока не произойдет "исключительная ситуация". Так вот собственно вопрос - функция блокируется или нет? Если не сложно, то объясните, пожалуйста, принцип действия функции.

2) Первый аргумент нашей функции представляет из себя целое число, на единицу большее максимального файлового дескриптора в любом из наборов. Скажите, пожалуйста, если мне интересен только один дескриптор - `5`, который я установил с помощью макроса `FD_SET()`, то функция прервется или нет, если я в дескрипторе `0` что нибудь напишу (и нажму `enter`)? В общем, мне не понятно, функция будет "следить" только за дескриптором `5` или за всеми от `0` до `5`?

Comment: Возможно вам больше понравится [poll](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Она блокируется, но длительность блокировки можно задать таймаутом. Если таймаут 0, то она в любом случае вернется сразу после выполнения проверок.

2) Изначально подразумевалось, что дескрипторы являются просто чиселками в интервале от 0 до некоторого максимума. А структура `fd_set` содержит массив битовых флагов которые могут быть проиндексированы этими чеселками. Такой подход позволял компактно представлять перечень обрабатываемых дескрипторов. Например, если максимум 1000, то потребуется всего 1000/8 = 125 байт и никакого динамического выделения памяти или сортировки. Если дескриптор 5, то пятый бит в первом байте будет выставлен в 1. Соответственно функция будет следить только за теми дескрипторами, соответствующий бит которых равен 1.